# Convert Discord.js v11 module to v12?

Tags: networking, bots, discord.js

I mostly have this discord bot working.  I am just having some trouble with this one module.  The root of the problem is that this code was written for discord.js v11.  I need to rewrite it for v12.
The original v11 module can be found here:
https://github.com/Meschdog18/disnet/blob/master/commands/broadcast.js

Here is what I have thus far:

```
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    var serverlist = client.guilds.cache.size;
    console.log(client.Networks)

    var server = message.guild.channels.cache;
    var Sender = client.Networks.get(message.guild.name);
    const input = args.join(" "); //rejoins arg array into string
    for (var i = 0; i < serverlist.length; i++) {
        //get network id of message sender
        var Recipient = client.Networks.get(serverlist[i].name);
        Recipient = parseInt(Recipient);



        if (Sender == Recipient) {
            try {
                var serv = serverlist[i].channels.cache.find(
                    serv => serv.name === "broadcast"
                );
                serv.send({
                    embed: {

                        /* author: { works but is disabled, because not sure if i like the look
                           name: "Disnet", 
                           icon_url: client.user.defaultAvatarURL
                         },*/
                        color: 0x3850eb,
                        title: "**__BROADCAST__**",

                        thumbnail: {
                            url: message.guild.iconURL
                        },
                        fields: [{
                                name: "Broadcasted From ",
                                value: message.guild.name
                            }, {

                                name: "Message",
                                value: input
                            }

                        ],
                        timestamp: new Date(),
                        footer: {
                            icon_url: message.author.avatarURL,
                            text: "Executed By " + message.author.username

                        }
                    }
                })
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                message.reply(
                    "You must create a #broadcast channel to recieve messages!"
                );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
exports.help = {
    name: "broadcast",
    description: "Broadcasts message to all servers on your network",
    usage: "N$broadcast <Message>"
};
exports.config = {
    permLevel: "admin"
}
```

This module is meant to have the bot transmit a message to every server in my network of discord servers. (it does use enmap and MySQL, but this module doesn't appear to use the SQL component(s))
It is not transmitting messages to the other servers in my network, but I am not getting any errors thrown in my terminal.  The bot just gives me this:

```
Enmap(2) [Map] {
  'Discord Sports & Athletics Associations' => 'DSAAnet',
  'NFL Discussion 2.0' => 'DSAAnet'
}
```

Which appears to be correct.  (DSAAnet is the name of the network, and the other two names are names of servers in the network.)
Is this correct?  What else do I need to change to make this v12 compatible?

Comment: https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html

Comment: `What's the error?`

Comment: That's the thing, there is no error message thrown.  The only thing I get in terminal is the Enmap message included in my OP.
@Jakye I have read that article but it simply says .array() has been removed from v12.  It doesn't tell you how to rewrite that string to be functional in v12.

Answer (score 0):

you can see every change on this website: [Updating from v11 to v12](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html)

Comment: It just says array() was removed.  It doesn't tell you what to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were reading this part.

---

### Collection#filterArray

`collection.filterArray()` was removed entirely, as it was just a helper method for `collection.filter().array()` and most of the time converting a collection to an array is an unnecessary step.

---

No, .array() was **never ever removed**.
And for your question, it says `.avatarURL`, `.iconURL`, `.defaultAvatarURL` is now `.avatarURL()`, `.iconURL()`, `.defaultAvatarURL()`

That should fix the issue :)

Comment: Even if I rem out the embed code and try to just send a basic text message instead I am still getting the same result: message not being transmitted and no error thrown.